# jQuery all documents-ready failed if one document-ready fails. Solution?

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

OK, here is an interesting question. Below are three jQuery modules. No one of them is gonna work. Otherwise they would work from first to last. And the reason they are not gonna work is missed `");` in the second block after the word `second`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
alert("first");
});

$(document).ready(function() {
alert("second
});


$(document).ready(function() {
alert("third");
});
```

Is there a way to execute other blocks, if we have no power to change the content of the second block?

[jsFiddle example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/4o24s7oy/)

Comment: No. Your entire script cannot be parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script block contains a syntax error.

Therefore, the parser completely rejects the entire block.

If you put the valid code in separate `<script>` tags, they will work fine.

Comment: Your comment says no, but your answer says Yes. Can I please downvote on your comment and vote for your answer as your answer looks valid? :D

Comment: @Haradzieniec this answer doesnt contredict his previous comment but explain it

Comment: @Haradzieniec: No, if you can't modify.  Yes, if you can split it into different scripts.

Answer (score 2):

Put them in separate script blocks.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("first");
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("second
  });
</script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("third");
  });
</script>
```